# Iteração dá erro de ConcurrentModificationException ao incluir mais de um botão

Tags: java, exceção

Tenho este pequeno jogo que estou a desenvolver em que a personagem passa por botões que vão retirar barreiras para que esta possa aceder a outras zonas do labirinto.

[image: imagem do jogo]

Eu criei duas listas, uma para as cercas e outra para os botões.

```
listaCercas = new ArrayList<Arbusto>();
listaCercas.add(new Arbusto(this,105, 496));
listaCercas.add(new Arbusto(this,660, 210));

listaBotoes = new ArrayList<Itens>();
listaBotoes.add(new Itens(this, 625, 460));
listaBotoes.add(new Itens(this, 200, 40));
```

E coloquei o seguinte código na parte das colisões:

```
Iterator<Itens> itbotao = listaBotoes.listIterator();
    Iterator<Arbusto> it6 = listaCercas.listIterator();
    while(it6.hasNext() && itbotao.hasNext()) {
        Arbusto cerca = it6.next();
        Itens botao = itbotao.next();
        Rectangle rBotao = new Rectangle(botao.x, botao.y, botao.botaoL, botao.botaoA);
        Rectangle rCerca = new Rectangle(cerca.x, cerca.y, cerca.cercaL, cerca.cercaA);
        if(rBoneca.intersects(rCerca)) {
            switch(direcao) {
                case 1:
                    bonecaSprite.y -= 5;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bonecaSprite.x -= 5;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bonecaSprite.x += 5;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    bonecaSprite.y += 5;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if((rBoneca.intersects(rBotao) && rBotao.getX() == 625) && !On_Off) {
            On_Off = true;
            listaCercas.remove(1);
        } else if((rBoneca.intersects(rBotao) && rBotao.getX() == 625) && On_Off) {
            On_Off = false;
            listaCercas.add(new Arbusto(this,660, 210));
        }
        if((rBoneca.intersects(rBotao) && rBotao.getX() == 200) && !On_Off) {
            On_Off = true;
            listaCercas.remove(0);
        } else if ((rBoneca.intersects(rBotao) && rBotao.getX() == 200) && On_Off) {
            On_Off = false;
            listaCercas.add(new Arbusto(this,105, 496));
        }
```

O meu código funciona se eu tiver só um botão, mas quando ponho o outro botão e o respectivo código o Java lança-me o erro: **`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`**.
Eu estive a pesquisar na net e a tentar compreender melhor o problema e vi que era sobre a parte da iteração mas não sei como o resolver. Como criar mais botões nos níveis seguintes e não ter que definir cada botão com uma variável?

Comment: Não analisei a lógica para entender a razão de você tentar remover sempre os elementos `0` ou `1`, mas se a ideia for remover o elemento atual da iteração você pode usar o método [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove\(\)) do próprio `Iterator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que você está alterando uma coleção sobre a qual está iterando (como em `listaCercas.remove(1)` e `listaCercas.add(new Arbusto(this,660, 210))`).
Em muitos casos pode acontecer de o iterador "se perder" quando um elemento da lista é removido.

A exceção é lançada quando há mais de um botão na coleção porque é o caso em que o código `it6.next()` será executado após a alteração da lista original.

Uma possível solução é clonar a lista que será alterada e iterar sobre o clone, removendo os elementos da lista original.

```
List<Arbusto> cloneCercas = new ArrayList<>(listaCercas);
Iterator<Arbusto> it6 = cloneCercas.iterator();
while(it6.hasNext() && itbotao.hasNext()) {
    Arbusto cerca = it6.next();
    Itens botao = itbotao.next();
    // código original...
    if(/* ... */) {
        listaCercas.remove(1);
    }
}
```

Outra possibilidade é criar uma lista com os elementos que devem ser removidos e, somente após o laço ter terminado, remover os elementos com o método `listaCercas.removeAll(cercasARemover)`.

Os mesmos conselhos valem para a adição de elementos as listas.
Cabe a você avaliar se será necessário levar em consideração as alterações da lista durante a iteração. :)