# Remover item de uma coleção

Tags: java, lista, for

Por que é considerado incorreto remover um objeto de uma coleção desta forma? E por que o lançamento da exceção `ConcurrentModificationException`?

```
for(String item: list) {
  list.remove(item);
}
```

Comment: [Acredito que isso resolva o problema e esclareça o motivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr)

Comment: Duplicatas ou relacionadas: [ConcurrentModificationException como proceder?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194745/concurrentmodificationexception-como-proceder) e [Iteração dá erro de ConcurrentModificationException ao incluir mais de um botão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18856/itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-d%C3%A1-erro-de-concurrentmodificationexception-ao-incluir-mais-de-um-bot%C3%A3o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `for` nesse modelo de *for each* existe um iterador, que é um mecanismo de controle dos itens que está na coleção para ir navegando pelos itens. Se você remove um item fica complicado continuar mantendo o iterador, é até possível que alguma implementação consiga se virar bem com isso, mas nem todas são garantidas que a iteração pode continuar sem problemas, pode nem ser possível saber mais quais são os próximos itens, pode ser que não consiga identificar mais quando acabaram os itens, pode até mesmo que acabe os itens prematuramente. Esse tipo de `for` existe para garantir que o acesso é coerente. Se deseja o risco e flexibilidade, ainda pode usar o `for` "bruto" e aí é problema seu iterar em cada item, ele deixa você fazer e assumir a responsabilidade por problemas.

E cada linguagem ou implementação pode ter suas próprias dificuldades.

Mas este erro pode não ocorrer. Eu fiz o que postou e não deu o erro:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        for (String i: list) {
            System.out.println("Antes => " + i);
            if (i == "b") list.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Depois => " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NXQVpE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aquvzywz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/RemoveFor.java).

Esta forma é mais garantida:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            String nome = i.next();
            System.out.println("Antes => " + nome);
            i.remove();
            System.out.println("Depois => " + nome);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zDC8vx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gylggeab-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/RemoveIterator.java).

Veja um exemplo onde pode ou não fazer exatamente o que se espera:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Passo " + i + " Antes => " + list.get(i));
            list.remove(list.get(i));
            System.out.println("Passo " + i + " Depois => " + list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s9fno4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rcfodslb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/RemoveForEach.java).

Após eliminar `b` ele já vai direto para `c`, era isto que queria? Nem sempre é o esperado, afinal você ainda está em um passo (o segundo) do laço que estava tratando de `b`. Mas é diferente do ocorrido nos casos acima.

Assim dá erro:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        for (String i: list) {
            System.out.println("Antes => " + i);
            list.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Depois => " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

É porque o iterador já deu erro. Note que ele não dá o erro preventivamente, ele dá quando efetivamente se perdeu.

Answer (score 4):

> por que o lançamento da exceção `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Essa exceção é lançada pois é um mecanismo de *fail-fast* para os casos onde existe qualquer modificação na coleção que estamos iterando.

Em outras palavras, antes que "de fato" dê problema, caso haja qualquer modificação na coleção, é feito o *trigger* da Exception.

---

Para contornar isso, você pode fazer o uso do [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).
Na verdade, o *for each* usa o `Iterator` por debaixo dos panos, mas para ser menos verboso, ele "esconde" o código completo e você não precisa digitar tudo sempre.

Para resolver o problema você pode fazer algo como:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String item = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
}
```